# JSON to parquet conversion or without conversion

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

We have a JSON file and we are converting into parquet. When we convert to parquet we get multiple small parquet files. How can we avoid these scenario? What is best and efficient way to handle this transformation?

This is sample data arriving in s3:

```
{
    "id": 100,
    "address": [{
        "location": "null",
        "locstatus": 5
    }],
    "lwd": null,
    "lwa": null
}
```

1. Is it good to convert to parquet format and combine small parquet
   files?
2. Is it good to keep the json files as is and merge multiple json files to load the data load?

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on your use-case. In general it is good to have less, bigger parquet files up to a certain size (~1GB). Sometimes you want more files though, to leverage the parallel processing power of Spark. It depends on the amount of worker nodes you have in place.

To change the amount of output files in Glue, you can repartition your DynamicFrame / DataFrame before writing:

```
df = dynamic_frame.repartition(number_of_files)
```

It also depends if you want Parquet, it's definitely a good file format for OLAP purposes. I would also advise you, to always keep your raw data, in this case probably your JSON files. Storage doesn't really cost anything anymore and you can reprocess your raw data in case you want to change something in the future.